# How to filter object array using underscoreJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

**(SOLVED, Check the solution in responses)**

***Question:***

I have an array of objects and I want to be able to filter only those that are equal to the object that I specify, I have tried in many ways but in the end I end up obtaining the same empty array.

I think the array returns empty because I'm iterating over an array of objects and not over a simple array.

Here I show my code:

***I have also placed the filter example that is shown in the underscoreJS documentation***

(Click on the button to show this result)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  /*
   *   START - My Filter using Underscore.js
   *
   */
  var arrObject = [{
    "data": [{
        "img": "test1"
      },
      {
        "img": "test2"
      },
      {
        "img": "/image_folder/sub_folder/886.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }];

  var compare = [{
    "img": "/image_folder/sub_folder/886.jpg"
  }];

  var finalArray;

  //console.log(arrObject);
  //console.log(compare);

  $.each(arrObject, function(index, element) {
    //console.log(element.data);
    finalArray = _.filter(element.data, function(ev) {
      return ev == compare;
    });
  });

  console.log(finalArray);

  /*
   *   END - My Filter using Underscore.js
   *
   */




  /*
   *   START - ORIGINAL Filter from Documentation Underscore.js
   *
   */
  $(document).on("click", ".originalUnderscore", function() {
      var evens = _.filter([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], function(num) {
      return num % 2 == 0;
    });
    console.log(evens);
  });
  /*
   *   END - ORIGINAL Filter from Documentation Underscore.js
   *
   */

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<button class="originalUnderscore">Click to show the original filter</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should use `_.isMatch(...)` when comparing object as `===` only compare references
Second, you were comparing an object `element.data[0]` with an array `compare`

So you code should look like :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const arrObject = [{
    "data": [{
        "img": "test1"
      },
      {
        "img": "test2"
      },
      {
        "img": "/image_folder/sub_folder/886.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }];

  const compare = {
    "img": "/image_folder/sub_folder/886.jpg"
  };

  $('.filterBtn').on('click', () => {
    let filtredArray = [];
    $.each(arrObject, (index, element) => {
      filtredArray = _.filter(element.data, function(ev) {
        return _.isMatch(ev, compare);
      });
      console.log(`filtredArray from data in element at index ${index}`);
      console.log(filtredArray);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<button class="filterBtn">Click filter</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your support bro! This example work's for me